# SQL: Need to hide a specific word(s) when they are used in a column -

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

My question right now is whether something can be done or not, as a result, no code has been included in this question. If it can be done what is the correct phrase that I can query and research this further.

I am working with a customer database where the request has been made that if a specific word is used in the comments field, that word is replaced or hidden when the query is used report and viewed using SSRS / Report Builder.

I had also wondered if even an expression can be written to hide or mask that word, and this would then be used in the tablix field that is used on the report.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

The database is Microsoft SQL 2016 with SSRS 2017 and Report Builder 2016.

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `SELECT REPLACE(MyColumn, 'MyWord', '') FROM MyTable`?

Comment: You can look at dynamic data masking if it fits your needs.

Comment: For an Expression in SSRS you could use `=REPLACE(Fields!COMMENTS.Value, "Bad Word", "")` similar to what @Sami has for SQL.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I don't see how schema, data, or expected output would help figure out which function would do a particular task.

Comment: If you show us some sample data and the expected output I can tell you what function to use. Otherwise, I would be guessing why you want. And I won’t waste my time guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a specific word, then the answer is simple.  You can just use `replace()`.  In fact, you can add this into the table:

```
alter table t add safe_comments as (replace(comments, '<bad word>', 'XXXXXXX'));
```

You can extend this to a handful of hard-coded words by nesting `replace()` values.

I suspect, however, that your problem is that you have a fairly long list of words that you want to replace.  If that is the case, such a simple solution is not going to work.

It is possible in SQL Server to remove a list of words, stored in a table, from a given comment.  That requires a recursive CTE (or a user-defined function).  This probably has acceptable performance for returning a single record or a handful of records.  However, for scanning the entire table, it would probably be too slow.

Comment: Sorry for the extreme delay in responding. This worked perfect and I appreciate the input folks. Made my day so much easier.